# How to train a keras ( tensorflow) model in java?

Tags: java, tensorflow, keras

I've searched how to achieve train a keras or tensorflow model in java but failed to proper example. There are lots of documents that describes the load the model in java-client but there is rarely documents that explain the both train and test the model in the java-side using keras model.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any opinion about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to keras, it about deep nueral networks. Python is the best programming language to train ML models since its supports lots of libraries on the Machine Learning domain. Once you trained a model, you can embed that with any programming language and build applications to make use of it.

You can refer the below link to train your tensorflow keras models using Java. But i dont know how much error free it is and the community support.

https://github.com/dhruvrajan/tensorflow-keras-java

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood from discussions with people who work with developing ML models is that even if the models gets deployed in different languages they usually use python to create the models because it's more simple then the alternative.